# VideoView on Android, 2 issues

Tags: android, video

Trying to get a simple video clip playing in a loop.  I got the video to play just fine.  However, there are two problems I'm having.

1. If the user clicks the Home button, effectively hiding the app.  Then they go back to it, the video is gone and doesn't reload.
   Everything as far as initializing the video only takes place in the typical onCreate for the view that holds it.  Where should I be calling the video from to start it to ensure that it always actually starts?
2. I can only get the device to find the video when pulling it from the web.  I see in the logs that when I try to reference the clip from the RAW folder, it cannot find it.

   ```
          VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.lighterView);
          myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.android.AndroidVideoPlayer/"+R.raw.[videoclip]));     
          myVideoView.requestFocus();
           myVideoView.start();

           myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
              @Override
              public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer myVideoView) {
                   myVideoView.setLooping(true);
              }
           });
   ```

The above chunk of code works fine if I use a URL to my website.  But locally, it cannot find the clip.

Comment: yes just load/play your video in onStart() method....

Comment: Ok.  That seems simple enough.  That takes care of that part.  Thanks.  Anyone have any idea why the local version of the clip cannot be found?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just load/play video in onStart() method I suggest you to look at some well written code about VideoView, because the best way to connect your video to your interface is manage your VideoView(that implements surfaceView) callBack.

You can find a good example at the following link;)

http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java.shtml

Comment: I've seen stuff about "surface view" while I was trying to figure this out.  In short, could you explain what the advantage is?  This app literally does NOTHING but play a video in a loop.  No interaction, nothing.

Comment: Personally I found the use of SurfaceView very intuitive, because the different callback are self explicative (surfaceCreated() --- surfaceDestroyed) and let you manage your video flow with no difficult. Moreover with this kind of structure you don't have to manage standby or situation like that, because implementing the surfaceView callBack in the right way assure  you that the UI goes along your video flow. Of course if you have only to show a simple video maybe is better to use view considering that surfaceview use more resources (it has its own buffer).

Comment: That's why I'm thinking it might be overkill for this.  I appreciate the suggestion though.  And I will read the link (the more you know...)